# SEO for a complex URL with multiple specifiers

Tags: seo, url, clean-urls

I have a jobs website. There are categories and sub categories e.g the URL for builders is `www.mydomain.com/jobs/all/active/202/tradesmen/799/builders/county/all`

Because of the framework I'm using (Elgg), the "all" and "active" come after the plugin name. Also, I need to do a lot of things with the URL: get the plugin (job), get the correct type of entities (all and active), get the category (202 and tradesmen), get the subcategory (799 & builders) and get the location (county and all). Is this URL SEO friendly or is it too messy? Is something like `www.mydomain.com/jobs/tradesmen/builders/all` better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is OK.

Consider two things:

1. use the all+active filters as defaults. that way you can omit them.
2. use [breadcrumbs rich snippet](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185417) so in search engines results pages (SERPs) the URL will be structured to represent the actual hierarchy.